# How to add SDK Location to Android Studio Beta

Tags: android-studio

My Android Studio seems can not save the SDK Location. I filled the location and click OK, exit and enter again, the location turn to blank.
Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: using which version of Android Studio? Try to run Android SDK Manager once to update it first.

Comment: Android Studio(Beta)0.8.14.  Android Studio and SDK are downloaded yesterday from offical web. They are latest. The problem is Android Studio can not remeber the location which I input. Finally I make it work by change the ANDROID_HOME to the latest SDK location. I checked the Android Studio logs, found it will use ANDROID_HOME as sdk location by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried creating/updating the local.properties file in the project-root directory?

```
 sdk.dir=C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\sdk\\Android\\sdk
```

after updating to Android Studio(Beta)0.8.14 android studio has asked me for this location and stored it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out the problem. The SDK which I got from web is nearly empty,only Build tool. The Android Studio think it as invalid SDK location. After downloading the SDK platform with SDK Manager, the SDK location can be saved.